# Removing all special characters using REGEXP_REPLACE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am able to remove all sepecial charaters as below:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('91D5 ZBA DISCONNECTION  https://mail.com/owa/#path=/mailÂ]*Debit Bank Ctry next Business Day is 06-Jan-2020', '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')  
FROM dual;
```

Output :

```
91D5 ZBA DISCONNECTION  https   mail tcs com owa  path  mail   Debit Bank Ctry next Business Day is 06 Jan 2020
```

However if there is any single inverted comma inside my description as below if fails how do I escape single inverted comma sequence using REGEXP_REPLACE function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('91D5 ZBA DISCONNECTION  https://mail.com/owa/#path=/''mailÂ]'*Debit Bank Ctry next Business Day is 06-Jan-2020', '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')  
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Text Literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA), e.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(q'#91D5 ZBA DISCONNECTION  https://mail.com/owa/#path=/''mailÂ]'*Debit Bank Ctry next Business Day is 06-Jan-2020#', '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')  
FROM dual;
```

> *quote_delimiter* is any single- or multibyte character except space,
>   tab, and return. The *quote_delimiter* can be a single quotation mark.
>   However, if the *quote_delimiter*appears in the text literal itself,
>   ensure that it is not immediately followed by a single quotation mark.
>
> If the opening *quote_delimiter*is one of [, {, <, or (, then the
>   closing *quote_delimiter* must be the corresponding ], }, >, or ). In
>   all other cases, the opening and closing *quote_delimiter* must be the
>   same character.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the reason the `Â` character is not being replaced is because the particular collation you are using treats `Â` and `A` as being the same character.  One possible workaround here would be to force a collation which distinguishes between the two characters when you query:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', ' ')
FROM yourTable
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I don't think collation is the problem here, TO likes to escape the single quote.